# Switch statement not working in class

Tags: c#

I'm developing a text-based RPG and I'm implementing a stat system. My code for the classes that interact with it is:

```
switch (charClass)
        {
            case "a":
                Player.charC(0);
                break;
            case "b":
                Player.charC(1);
                break;
            case "c":
                Player.charC(2);
                break;
        }

public static void charC(int charPath)
    {
        switch (charPath)
        {
            case 0:
                Player.stats(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                Player.stats(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                Player.stats(2);
                break;
        }
    }

 public static void stats(int stat)
    {

        Player p = new Player();

        switch (stat)
        {
            case 0:
                p.m_health = 200;
                p.m_mana = 75;
                p.fast = 7;
                p.strng = 20;
                p.smrt = 7;
                p.move = 7;
                p.level = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                p.m_health = 100;
                p.m_mana = 200;
                p.fast = 10;
                p.strng = 7;
                p.smrt = 15;
                p.move = 7;
                p.level = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                p.m_health = 100;
                p.m_mana = 100;
                p.fast = 10;
                p.strng = 10;
                p.smrt = 10;
                p.move = 10;
                p.level = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

When I try to run it, it returns all the stats as 0.

Example: MAX HEALTH 0. MAX MANA 0. FAST 0. STRONG 0. SMART 0.

Comment: I bet you placed a breakpoint and single-stepped through the code already, didn't you?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: **1.** Re: _"it returns all the stats as 0"_, what does that mean in terms of the code you've shown us? **2.** Re: _"When I try to run it"_: …with what specific input (`charClass`?) to the code you've shown us?

Comment: Show a short, compiling sample code which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: It's a jumble of code, but the basics are that a player selects a class and it chooses stats for the character.

Comment: I can say with absolute certainty that the problem isnt the switch statement, what does `stats(0)` do? (FYI the `charC` switch statement isnt needed at all)

Comment: How do you call the first switch statement, you are editing a **new** player in your stats method

Comment: Stackoverflow is so nice. You insert bad code, and good code automatically comes out. Right?

Comment: @Sayse I'm newer to C#, but still get the gist of what you're saying. Not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: what calls the `switch(charClass)`? I'd imagine you need an instance of Player instead of a call to a static method

Comment: @user3233136 Please, just place a breakpoint, and step through the code line by line. Each time, check whether the relevant variables contain the values that they are expected to contain. You **will** find out what is wrong this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `stats` method you're not returning the player object. You create a new player, set its properties, but discard the object at the end of the method.

In short: You're not working on the object you think you're working on.

---

Why is all this `static`?

Comment: Thank you. This helped tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the static-ness of stats and call it with the instance of the player

```
public void stats(int stat)
{
    switch (stat)
    {
        case 0:
            m_health = 200;
            m_mana = 75;
            fast = 7;
            strng = 20;
            smrt = 7;
            move = 7;
            break;
        case 1:
            m_health = 100;
            m_mana = 200;
            fast = 10;
            strng = 7;
            smrt = 15;
            move = 7;
            break;
        case 2:
            m_health = 100;
            m_mana = 100;
            fast = 10;
            strng = 10;
            smrt = 10;
            move = 10;
            break;
    }
    level = 1;
}
```

---

use the instance of player in both switches, i.e

```
    switch (charClass)
    {
        case "a":
            playerInstance.charC(0);
            break;
        case "b":
            playerInstance.charC(1);
            break;
        case "c":
            playerInstance.charC(2);
            break;
    }

public void charC(int charPath)
{
    switch (charPath)
    {
        case 0:
            this.stats(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            this.stats(1);
            break;
        case 2:
            this.stats(2);
            break;
    }
}
```